# VSCode debug configuration for Next.js Frontend with Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm-scripts, vscode-debugger

In my project directory I have a frontend in next.js and a backend in Node.js it looks as follows:

[image]

I now would like to debug the program, so both backend and frontend have to run, and I don't know how to create the corrent debug launch.json configuration which I have in my top-level project, to launch and debug both programs.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"compounds": [
    {
        "name": "Client+Server",
        "configurations": [ "DCBACKEND", "DCFRONTEND" ]
    }
],
"configurations": [        
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "DCBACKEND",
        "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}\\dcbackend",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run-script", "start"
        ]
    },
    {            
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "DCFRONTEND",
        "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}\\dcfrontend",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\dcfrontend\\pages\\index.js",
        "runtimeExecutable": "next",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--inspect"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

EDIT: Now, I get the following error:

[image]

My start script for my backend is:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js -p 7766"
  },
```

so there is something wrong with the port maybe? Also, it runs another script for debug in cmd-line:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd run-script start --inspect-brk=39777
```

I don't know what it has to do with `--inspect-brk=39777`, do I need that

Comment: Surely the `cwd` should be the backend and frontend directories, not the project root? Also why does the root have a `package-lock.json` but no `package.json`?

Comment: I dont know why my top level folder has a package.lock.json it also shouldnt have a package.json. I fixed my command : `{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "DCBACKEND",
            "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}\\dcbackend",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script", "start"
            ]
        }`  but still, it does not work although the start script now looks fine and I am in the right folder with package.json

Comment: Has the error *changed*, at least? [Edit] the question.

Comment: yes , I edited in my post above